# Rails4.2 carrierwave_backgrounderについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

carrierwave_backgrounderを使い画像のアップロードを非同期にしました。
開発環境では正しく動くのですが、herokuにデプロイしたらキューが開始されません

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

AmazonのS3を使用していて、エラー内容をみると/app/public/uploads/tmp/となっているのでおかしいというのはわかるのですが、どこを直せばいいかわかりません

carrierwave_backgrounderを使う前はheroku環境でもアップロードできました。

```
# app/uploaders
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  version :thumb1 do
    process :resize_to_limit => [840,1336]
  end

  version :thumb2 do
    process :resize_to_limit => [420,840]
  end

  version :thumb3 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
  end

  # CarrierWaveでアップロードした写真（画像）が回転して表示されるのを直す
  process :fix_rotate
  def fix_rotate
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.auto_orient
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  # バッググランド処理
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  # S3 strage
  storage :fog

  # 画像の上限を700pxにする
  process :resize_to_limit => [1366, 1366]

  # 保存形式をJPGにする
  process :convert => 'jpg'

  # 許可する画像の拡張子
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

# 変換したファイルのファイル名の規則
  def filename
    "#{secure_token}.png" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
  end
end



# config/initializer/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      :aws_secret_access_key  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      :region => 'ap-northeast-1'
  }


  config.fog_directory = 'appnamedevelopment' if Rails.env.development?
  config.fog_directory = 'appnameproduction' if Rails.env.production?
end


# config/initializer/carrierwave_backgrounder.rb
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  c.backend :sidekiq, queue: :carrierwave
end
```

## 変更後

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  config.fog_credentials = {
        :provider               => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        :aws_secret_access_key  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        :region => 'ap-northeast-1'
  }

  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_directory = 'appnamedevelopment' if Rails.env.development?
  config.fog_directory = 'appnameproduction' if Rails.env.production?
  config.fog_public = true
  config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 60
end
```

## エラー

```
Rendering 500 with exception: undefined method `cache_name' for #<CarrierWave::Mounter:0x007fd0bd830d98>
```

Comment: 問題はキューが開始されないことであっていますか？
キューは開始されているが、処理に失敗している、という状態に見受けられます。

config/initializer/carrierwave.rb、および、該当の app/uploaders 
の内容を追記できるでしょうか？
より詳しいことがわかると思います。

Comment: 失礼しました。ご指摘の通り、キューは開始されるが処理に失敗するが正解です。情報を追記しました。ご確認頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

carrierwave ではなく、heroku に原因があるのかもと思います。

carrierwave は、ファイルをアップロードするとき、一旦キャッシュディレクトリに置きます。

```
クライアント → サーバ上のキャッシュディレクトリ → S3
```

backgrounder を使うと、キャッシュに置いた状態で、処理をキューに委譲します。

```
クライアント → サーバ上のキャッシュディレクトリ (← ココで処理は終了)
sidekiq:  サーバ上のキャッシュディレクトリ → S3
```

エラーは、sidekiq が`キャッシュディレクトリに置いてあるファイル`が見つからないよ、と言っています。
sidekiq が動いているサーバと、アプリケーションが動いているサーバが別だったりしないでしょうか？

解法としては、下記の記事を見つけました。
[CarrierwaveでS3にアップロードさせるとき、キャッシュもS3に置く - Qiita](http://qiita.com/doima_/items/677a8acbcaf018dd9ec9#comment-f2a6a5996b005d2b9001)

または、store_in_background を使わないという選択肢もあるかと思います。
(レスポンスが許せば、ですが)

参考
[Ruby - HerokuでCarrierWaveを使う場合に注意すること - Qiita](http://qiita.com/Oakbow/items/802da14fa3cf67763ba7)

Comment: ありがとうございます。追記のように修正したのですがRendering 500 with exception: undefined method `cache_name' for とエラーになってしまいます。参考URLに記載のある:qconfig.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"って:qはいらないですよね・・

Comment: もともとはgem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0' を入れていましたが、gem 'carrierwave',github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'と入れ直すとundefined method `cache_name'になります。

Comment: スミマセン。よく確認せずにオススメしてしまいました。
最新の carrierwave は開発版のものなので、不安定なのだと思います。
他の解法で解決された方が良いかもしれません。

この解法で続ける場合は、500 になった状況を追記されると良いかと思います。500 ということは、アクセスした時のエラーかと思いますが、どのような時に発生したエラーなのか、読み取れませんでした。
ご質問の内容であるアップロード自体は、解決したのでしょうか？

Comment: アクセスしてもundefined method `cache_nameになります。最新の carrierwaveを入れると、何をやってもundefined method `cache_nameがでるのでgit reset --hard HEADで戻しました。アップロード（非同期でする）は解決していません、非同期でなければできますが・・スマホからアップすると5秒もかかるのでダメですね、railsでサービスを作ってる人はどうやって実装しているんでしょうか、あまり記事がなくて困っています。